# Pattern for specific substitution

Tags: r, gsub

I have this object:

```
nr.genes<-structure(c("0", "Pipas_chr3_1145", "Pipas_chr3_1145", "Pipas_chr1-4_0581", 
"Pipas_chr1-4_0582", "Pipas_chr1-4_0584", "Pipas_chr2-1_0006", 
"Pipas_chr2-2_0010", "Pipas_chr3_0002", "0", "0", "Pipas_c034_0013", 
"Pipas_chr1-4_0582", "Pipas_chr3_0002", "Pipas_chr4_0878", "Pipas_chr4_1001", 
"Pipas_chr4_0878", "Pipas_chr4_1001", "0", "Pipas_chr1-4_0581", 
"Pipas_chr1-4_0582", "Pipas_chr2-2_0010", "Pipas_chr3_0002", 
"Pipas_chr4_0878", "Pipas_chr4_1001", "0", "Pipas_c131_0003", 
"Pipas_chr1-1_0281", "Pipas_chr1-3_0004", "Pipas_chr3_1145", 
"Pipas_chr4_0003", "Pipas_c034_0013", "Pipas_c131_0003", "Pipas_chr1-3_0004", 
"Pipas_chr3_1145", "Pipas_chr4_0003", "0"), .Names = c("Nr11", 
"Nr12", "Nr13", "Nr141", "Nr142", "Nr143", "Nr144", "Nr145", 
"Nr146", "Nr21", "Nr22", "Nr23", "Nr241", "Nr242", "Nr311", "Nr312", 
"Nr321", "Nr322", "Nr33", "Nr341", "Nr342", "Nr343", "Nr344", 
"Nr345", "Nr346", "Nr41", "Nr421", "Nr422", "Nr423", "Nr424", 
"Nr425", "Nr431", "Nr432", "Nr433", "Nr434", "Nr435", "Nr44"))
```

and I would like to change the names by this ones:

```
nr.genes.names<-c("up.p33-dw.p33", "up.p33-dw.p38", "up.p33-dw.p52", "up.p33-dw.p64", 
"up.p38-dw.p33", "up.p38-dw.p38", "up.p38-dw.p52", "up.p38-dw.p64", 
"up.p52-dw.p33", "up.p52-dw.p38", "up.p52-dw.p52", "up.p52-dw.p64", 
"up.p64-dw.p33", "up.p64-dw.p38", "up.p64-dw.p52", "up.p64-dw.p64"
)
```

So the final result of `nr.genes` should be

```
structure(c("0", "Pipas_chr3_1145", "Pipas_chr3_1145", "Pipas_chr1-4_0581", 
"Pipas_chr1-4_0582", "Pipas_chr1-4_0584", "Pipas_chr2-1_0006", 
"Pipas_chr2-2_0010", "Pipas_chr3_0002", "0", "0", "Pipas_c034_0013", 
"Pipas_chr1-4_0582", "Pipas_chr3_0002", "Pipas_chr4_0878", "Pipas_chr4_1001", 
"Pipas_chr4_0878", "Pipas_chr4_1001", "0", "Pipas_chr1-4_0581", 
"Pipas_chr1-4_0582", "Pipas_chr2-2_0010", "Pipas_chr3_0002", 
"Pipas_chr4_0878", "Pipas_chr4_1001", "0", "Pipas_c131_0003", 
"Pipas_chr1-1_0281", "Pipas_chr1-3_0004", "Pipas_chr3_1145", 
"Pipas_chr4_0003", "Pipas_c034_0013", "Pipas_c131_0003", "Pipas_chr1-3_0004", 
"Pipas_chr3_1145", "Pipas_chr4_0003", "0"), .Names = c("up.p33-dw.p33", 
"up.p33-dw.p38", "up.p33-dw.p52", "up.p33-dw.p64", "up.p33-dw.p64", 
"up.p33-dw.p64", "up.p33-dw.p64", "up.p33-dw.p64", "up.p33-dw.p64", 
"up.p38-dw.p33", "up.p38-dw.p38", "up.p38-dw.p52", "up.p38-dw.p64", 
"up.p38-dw.p64", "up.p52-dw.p33", "up.p52-dw.p33", "up.p52-dw.p38", 
"up.p52-dw.p38", "up.p52-dw.p52", "up.p52-dw.p64", "up.p52-dw.p64", 
"up.p52-dw.p64", "up.p52-dw.p64", "up.p52-dw.p64", "up.p52-dw.p64", 
"up.p64-dw.p33", "up.p64-dw.p38", "up.p64-dw.p38", "up.p64-dw.p38", 
"up.p64-dw.p38", "up.p64-dw.p38", "up.p64-dw.p52", "up.p64-dw.p52", 
"up.p64-dw.p52", "up.p64-dw.p52", "up.p64-dw.p52", "up.p64-dw.p64"
))
```

But if I try with these expression I don't get it right:
`attr(nr.genes, "names") <- nr.genes.names[as.integer(gsub('^Nr[0-9]([0-9]).*','\\1',attr(nr.genes, "names")))]`

I think the problem is in the pattern or in the replacement because I just get the first 4  names in their place and after that they are repeated. I have just seen `chartr()` by I don't see it would help. How could I improve the `gsub`?

Edit: I want to change from

```
Nr11 by up.p33-dw.p33
Nr12 by up.p33-dw.p38
Nr13 by up.p33-dw.p52
Nr14 by up.p33-dw.p64
Nr21 by up.p38-dw.p33
Nr22 by up.p38-dw.p38
Nr23 by up.p38-dw.p52
Nr24 by up.p38-dw.p64
Nr31 by up.p52-dw.p33
Nr32 by up.p52-dw.p38
Nr33 by up.p52-dw.p52
Nr34 by up.p52-dw.p64
Nr41 by up.p64-dw.p33
Nr42 by up.p64-dw.p38
Nr43 by up.p64-dw.p52
Nr44 by up.p64-dw.p64
```

Comment: What is the rule for matching new names to old names? It is not at all obvious from the sample data.

Comment: @SimonO101 I hope this way it is clear, the third number it doesn't matter, so Nr121  will be substituted by the same than Nr122 in this case up.p33-dw.p38

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `regexp`'s here. You can `strtrim` your names to the characters that matter, and then use to `match`  like this...

```
#  Get a vector of the unique elements of the bits of the old names we want to match against
idx <- sort( unique( strtrim(names(nr.genes),4) ) )
# [1] "Nr11" "Nr12" "Nr13" "Nr14" "Nr21" "Nr22" "Nr23" "Nr24" "Nr31" "Nr32" "Nr33" "Nr34" "Nr41" "Nr42"
#[15] "Nr43" "Nr44"

#  Match the old names to their position in the 'idx' vector, 
#  and use this as an index vector to select the new names
#  from 'nr.genes.names'.
#  This works because 'nr.gene.names' is sorted the same way
#  as 'idx', i.e. in ascending order.
new <- nr.genes.names[ match( strtrim(names(nr.genes),4) , idx ) ]

#  assign new names
names( nr.genes ) <- new
```

Comment: Nice, simple and useful, and great comments! Thanks

Comment: @Llopis you are welcome. And a +1 for you for showing input data, what you wanted as output and what you tried and why it didn't work. A well formed question (although fewer data next time would make it more readable).